# Why WDS required NTFS partition for storing images

Tags: windows, ntfs

it says    [HERE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj648426.aspx)  under "Prerequisites for installing Windows Deployment Services" that WDS requires NTFS for storing images. Can anyone explain me why is it so?

I hope I'm asking at the right place

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Answering the question 'why?' will not change the fact that it is a requirement.

Comment: @Tetsujin No, but it's an interesting technical question nonetheless. Could also lead to a follow-up "Is it possible to create (or does there already exist) an alternative solution that doesn't need NTFS?" - but that's probably more off-topic.

Comment: Probably because it's a MS platform and NTFS is their "baby" that can hold files of greater than 4GB and have permissions and attributes applied that their other filesystems can't. Why should they make it work on non-MS filesystems?